# Selenium WebDriver Locator

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

Вторые сутки пытаюсь найти данный элемент в сервисе mail.ru. Локатор то я делаю, но все равно он ловит либо кнопку подписи, либо ничего. Если кто-то подскажет, буду благодарен)
[image: в селениуме]

Comment: либо же получаю org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotInteractableException: element not interactable

Answer (score 0):

В свое время тоже мучился с этим элементом. Смотри внимательно, там все работает через iframe элемент, а чтобы с ним взаимодействовать, нужно переключиться на него с помощью вызова `webDriver.switchTo().frame(webElement)` и обратно на основной фрэйм с помощью вызова `webDriver.switchTo().defaultContext()`

Этот код работает:

```
WebElement iframe = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td/iframe"));
driver.switchTo().frame(iframe);
WebElement iframeBody = driver.findElement(By.id("tinymce"));
iframeBody.click();
iframeBody.sendKeys("\n" + text);
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```